# How can I retrieve the audio data sent to chromecast audio?

Tags: linux, audio, streaming, chromecast, ethernet

For checking purpose, is there any way to retrieve the audio data sent to chromecast audio on linux platform?

Comment: Please provide more details, like how you like to do it. Better, show what you have done so far with your script or program.

Comment: Thanks @jww for your interest. The reason for asking was because I was having problem with the sound quality and wanted to check the quality of the data received by the chromecast device. The sound issue was caused by poor system performance and linux swap making the system to run slowly.